# Apex Interactive Debugger Not Streaming to VS Code

Tags: apex-debugger

I have been using the interactive debugger for quite a while now. Recently after refreshing my sandbox the debugger seems to have stopped working.

I can see the session in my org:
[image]

VS Code Says its connected:
[image]

There are no errors. My config is:

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Launch Apex Debugger",
          "type": "apex",
          "request": "launch",
          "sfdxProject": "${workspaceRoot}",
      }
  ]
```

I've also tried with user filter on my own user Id.

Normally when debugging if you have filters in place you can see messages saying events will not be debugged as a result of the filters; however, these messages are not displayed.

I've tested vf pages, triggers, test classes, etc. My breakpoints are all verified. I have a permission set with the correct permissions. I'm on the most recent versions of Java 8, VS Code, and The Salesforce Extensions Pack.

It simply connects, waits 20 minutes until it times out, and disconnects. As far as I can tell Salesforce is simply not streaming the events.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you add a breakpoint to the very beginning of the execution context it registers the breakpoint. If you only have breakpoints towards the end of the execution context, it may not catch them.

So to resolve I simply add a breakpoint to the first line of code that I expect to execute (this is easy in test classes) and then a breakpoint on the line I actually want to test. When it stops on the first breakpoint simply click the "play" button to tell it to run through to the second.